# Отпустить кривую линию.

Tags: html, css

Данный код не срабатывает, браузер приписывает ширине значение padding'а. Линия становится квадратом. Фигура не отпускается.

```
#curve2 {
padding-top: 120px;
height: 2px;
width: 120px;
background: #000;
transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чем margin-top не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

На выбор:

```
#curve2 {
  margin-top: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```
#curve2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```